# Одно действие по двум событиям в jQuery

Tags: jquery

ajax запрос вызывается по двум действиям:

через нажатие кнопки:

```
$('#start-button').click(function(event){ ajax ...});
```

и через нажатие Enter:

```
$('html').keydown(function(eventObject){ //отлавливаем нажатие клавиш
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { ajax...} })
```

Чуствую, что дублировать код ajax не правильно. Как объеденить эти два события?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ ?

Comment: по формулировке выглядит так, как будто вы хотите реализовать ajax форму, если это так, то все ваше отслеживание 2ух событий - костыль. Приведите пример разметки для вашей логики.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вынести запрос в отдельную функцию, например, и вызывать её.